# Display result of js calculation in span

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to calculate something in javascript and then display the result in a `<span></span>`.
This is the code that I've got at the moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
 function minus_number() {
        var first_number = '50';
        var second_number = '30';
        var result = parseInt(first_number) - parseInt(second_number);

        document.getElementById('spend').value = result;
    }
}
```

And the html

```
<p><i class="fa fa-truck"></i>Want free delivery? Spend an extra <span id="spend"></span> for free standard delivery</p>
```

It doesn't actually display the result in the span though, can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Call your function using `event listener`.

```
function minus_number() {
        var a  = document.querySelector("#spend");
        var first_number = '50';
        var second_number = '30';
        var result = parseInt(first_number) - parseInt(second_number);
        a.innerHTML = result;
    }
window.addEventListener("load",minus_number());
```

Answer (score 5):

**You should use `innerHTML` instead of `value`.**

Replace

```
document.getElementById('spend').value = result;
```

with

```
document.getElementById('spend').innerHTML = result;
```

`value` is for form elements and `innerHTML` is used if you want to set the content of any other element.

Read more about `innerHTML` in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 1):

The crucial function `minus_number` was only declared in your code, but it wasn't called.
Also, you should use `textContent` or `innerHTML` property instead of `value`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
    function minus_number() {
        var first_number = '50';
        var second_number = '30';
        var result = parseInt(first_number) - parseInt(second_number);

        document.getElementById('spend').textContent = result;
    }
    minus_number();  //  <--- calling function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line `document.getElementById('spend').value = result;`
in 
`document.getElementById('spend').textContent = result;`